# Why does the loop print 0 at the end?

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

This is an example I found on a website. The result is really different from what I expected. But there is no further explain.

```
int num = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{  
    num += num++;
}

System.out.println(num);
```

Finally, the result will print `0`. I am really confused about  the operation `num += num++`. Can someone explain this?

Comment: You need to understand what the difference is between pre-increment and post-increment.

Comment: Why would you do that? (`num += num++`)

Comment: Would it be `int otherNumber = num++`, it would be fine. Otherwise, this kind of code is confusing and useless. Assigning and incrementing the same values is useless.

Comment: @AlonAlexander This is just a question I found somewhere. The answer is really different from what I expected, but there was no explain.

Comment: *The result is really different from what I expected.* What did you expect? Why?

Answer (score 8):

`num++` increments num `after` the instruction (it is a post-increment operator).
So `num += num++;` assigns `0` to `num` (num = 0 + 0 + 0).

After the instruction `num += num++;` the post increment of `num` (that is `num++`) has no effect as `num` was assigned to another value (that is `num += 0` which the result is `0`) . 
So `num` is valued to `0`.
And so on for each iteration.

Replace `num += num++` by `++num` that is the pre-increment operator, you will get the result : `3` (as you increment 1 by iteration).

Comment: @qtips Indeed. replace `num += num++` by `++num`  Thank you.

Comment: What I thought is that `num += num++` equals to `num = num + num++`. If `num++` increaments num after the instruction. Here the result is `num = 0 + 0 = 0`. Afte this instruction, why the `++` operation has no effect?

Comment: These two statements produce exactly the same result. In your actual code, the problem is in the fact that `num=0` and you assign its post increment to itself. It has never the chance to be different from 0 since it is a post increment. And after the instruction `num += num++;`, the post increment of `num` has not effect as `num` was assigned to another value. Try you code with `num= 1` for example, you will see the difference.

Answer (score 6):

This assignment

```
 num += num++;
```

invokes two different rules in java: one on the left side, one on the right side.

The right side rule is fairly well known: the value of the post-increment operator is the value of the variable before the increment. This makes the value of `0++` a zero.

The other rule is a bit more obscure (I was not aware of the left side rule).

According to "15.7.1. Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First" in [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) Java first decides just what gets assigned, and also **what is its value**. Then the right side of `+=` is computed.

With these two rules in mind, the assignment above is the equivalent of:

```
temp1 = num // and will assign to num
temp2 = num // before ++
num = num + 1
num = temp1 + temp2
```

As you can see, the last line adds the original value of `num` (it happens to be `0`) to the value of `num` before ++, which ensures that `num` does not change. It starts at `0`, it ends with `0`.

Suppose that you're now using a pre-increment operator:

```
 num += ++num;
```

Now the situation is sligthly different.

```
int temp1 = num // and num will be assigned
int temp2 = num = num + 1
num = temp1 + temp2
```

The value of `num` used in `num += xxx` is not the result of `++num` - it is the value we had before `++num` was executed.

So first iteration we have `0+=1`, second iteration it's `1+=2` and third iteration it's `3+=4` - that's `7`

Comment: What if I replace `num++` by `++num`? Is equivalent of `num = num +1; temp = num; num+= temp;`?

Comment: This is not true! The "equivalent" code that you have written actually outputs 7. (I just ran it to make certain).

Comment: Rolled back, investigating

Comment: @PeterHall - how's that?

Comment: Your first "equivalent" code example, still outputs 7. It's not equivalent.

Comment: Correct answer but why do you say that `num += num++;` is equivalent to `temp = num;
num = num + 1;
num += temp` ? It doesn`t. Try with num=0, the first case  finishes with num value to 0 but the second one with num value to 1.